# Add active class to an element in a ngFor loop before click event is fired

Tags: angular

I have a simple ngFor loop that loads a dynamic "menu"

**component.html :**

```
<ul class="nav-series">
    <li *ngFor="let seriesItem of seriesList, let i = index" [class.active]='selectedIndex === i'>
        <a (click)="[selectVehicles(seriesItem.seriesGroup), setIndex(i)]">{{ seriesItem.seriesGroup }}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**component.ts :**

```
setIndex(index: number) {
    this.selectedIndex = index;
}
```

This all works fine and adds the class active to the clicked item. but what i do want is to have the class active applied to a specific item within the loop as default - before click.

Comment: Then set default specific value to selectedIndex.

Comment: `import ActivatedRoute from @angular/route` and it can help you to get the url params. on page load you should check `url params` and active that menu, while on change you can apply your above logic which is already working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize selectedIndex with the index

E.g.,

```
public selectedIndex = 0; (Will highlight the first element)
```

Answer (score 0):

in ngOnInit add this.selectedIndex=seriesList[0];
this will set your selectedIndex to 1st element of your array and class will apply. basically this will select 1st element from the array by default

```
ngOnInit(){
 this.selectedIndex= seriesList[0];
}
```